# How to debug large Polars pl.select - narrow down offending row

Tags: python-polars

when I encounter a panic error in a select query, how do I narrow down which is / are the offending expressions

Edit:
simply by looking at the logs / setting a Param. Without having to alter the code into a sequential binary search for loop.

```
pl.select([
  expr1, expr2, expr3 .... 
])
```

Comment: remove half of them - if it still fails, remove another half, else put back half. repeat

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
pl.select([
expr1, expr2, expr3 .... 
])
```

isolate the list

```
exprlist=[expr1, expr2, expr3 .... ]
```

Then do something like:

```
for i, expr in enumerate(exprlist):
    try:
        pl.select(expr)
    except:
        print(f"{i} is bad")
```

Comment: While a for loop may work, this is not ideal when trying to look into issues in aproductiom environment where I may not have the luxury of altering the code ans rerunning. The input data may also not be easily reproducible. I would have thought it wouldn't be hard for the select function to log the offending expression strings if an error occurs, along with the stack trace

Comment: I guess that's the pitfall of asking vague questions.